# elementary OS makes my router reboot, why?

Tags: networking

I'm not totally sure if it is only elementary OS or all Linux distributions.

I been seeing this for months but do not have a clue about the reason. When I use a computer with elementary, my router reboots, on something like 1 time per hour. I have two computers with elementary OS being used everyday, when I use OS X everything goes fine, until some computer with elementary gets powered on, then, the pattern begins.

there is some way I can diagnose this?

Answer (score 4):

elementary OS does not have any management access to your router. If this is really caused by Linux (elementary OS uses the same network stack as every other distribution), it's your router's fault. You might want to contact your router supplier (which you did not specify yet).

Comment: They told me that it happens when it accumulates too much package transfer errors, besides that they were clueless too